# Is the sentence "I saw him saying..." right?

Tags: sense-verbs

Is the following sentence right in any way:

> *I saw him saying that to the Chairman*

instead of the more acceptable

> *I heard him saying that to the Chairman*?

I have a sense that the first sentence focuses more on the action and the second one on the fact, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: It makes no sense to me. You could say *I saw him talking to the Chairman*. But if you are referring to something specific which he said, it would have to be 'heard' - unless you are a lip reader!

Comment: You can see someone talking from across the room, but generally only hear them if they are next to you.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are grammatical but mean different things. One uses one's eyes to see the images and one's ears to hear the sounds involved in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Both could be used, but it largely depends on the context. Let's say you are a in a court of law as a witness. A prosecutor could ask you:

> You just stated you heard him saying that. Did you personally see him (pointing at a defendant) saying that to the Chairman?

You could answer:

> Yes, I (personally/in person) saw him saying that to the Chairman.

This conversation might not take place very frequently, but is not impossible.